# ethers.js - How to derive child addresses + private keys from HD private key

Tags: hd-wallets

I have a HD private key which I have derived from my mnemonic using the `ethers` library. I would now like to derive child addresses and corresponding private keys from it.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

This is how I have obtained the HD private key:

`const xKey = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(...)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic** is used to create the master private key out of they mnemonic, but for creating new pairs of public and private keys I think you should use this method with different passphrase for each pair:

```
const HDNode  = await ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(YOUR_MNEMONIC, null, YOUR_PASSPHRASE);
```

When you check the new generated HDNode inside of it you can see it contains the same mnenomic you used for the master private key.

Answer (score 2):

```
const derived = xKey.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");
```

You should use the **derivePath** function of the master key, specifying the path of the derived keys.

See more [bip-32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) and [hdnode](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-advanced.html#hdnode).

Comment: FYI to others, this is the typical way we generate derived keys. We can simply increase the index to get more keys. "m/44'/60'/0'/0/n" See https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84 for more info.